# Covering index adventureworks 2008 R2 - Why is column WorkorderID not included?

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

A covering non-clustered index is created to meet the requirements of a given query.
If one column is not present in an index then SQL server will require to execute a key lookup. To prevent a key lookup, a covering index is created, but what I don't understand is why the following is a covering index while one of the columns is not included.

Database:  Adventureworks 2008 R2
Table:     Production.WorkOrder
Index name: IX_WorkOrder_ProductID

Query:

```
SELECT WorkOrderID,StartDate
FROM Production.WorkOrder
WHERE ProductID = 757;
```

The index IX_WorkOrder_ProductID starts with only the column ProductID
It's dropped and re-created as follows:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_WorkOrder_ProductID
ON Production.WorkOrder (ProductID)
INCLUDE (StartDate);
```

After executing the actual execution plan uses index seek (non-clustered) with a cost of
100%.

My question is: Why is it not required to include the column WorkOrderID to the index
IX_WorkOrder_ProductID also? Why is it a covering index without WorkOrderID ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `WorkOrderID` is the clustered index on that table `Production.WorkOrder`, it is **already** and automatically included in every single non-clustered index that you create on that table.

There's really no need to include that again - it's already there.

So your new index `IX_WorkOrder_ProductID` is in fact covering the query - the `WorkOrderID` is present due to the fact the clustering key is present in **every** non-clustered index anyway, and the `ProductID` column is part of the index definition.

Since the clustering index key(s) is (are) included in every single non-clustered index on that table is one more reason why the clustering key should be chosen very carefully, and should be as small as possible - ideally an `INT` or `BIGINT`.